# Metodos Funcionales Java

Tags: java, poo

estoy aprendiendo a usar la programacion funcional de java 8 y no se por que pero no consigo hacer que me funcione el código. 
El problema que tengo es que todo va bien hasta que quiero asignar 2 variables de la clase, puedo una, pero al intentar hacer la segunda peta el prográma. 
Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

```
class Camello{
    private String nombre;
    private Boolean soborno;
    private Boolean libertad;
    private int h;
    public Camello(String nombre) {
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }

    public static Camello parir(String nombre) {
        return new Camello(nombre);
    }

    public void venderHierva(int kilos) {
        System.out.println("Su camello le ha vendido "+kilos+" de maria");
        this.h=kilos;
    }
    public void sobornar(boolean soborno) {
        this.soborno=soborno;
    }
}

public class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Camello.parir("Gustabo")
               .venderHierva(100)
               .sobornar(true);   //Aqui da error, me dice que no puedo asignar
                                  //Datos con el tipo primitivo booleano

    }
}
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de a qué le llamas _programación funcional en java_, pero lo cierto es que `parir` devuelve una instancia de `Camello`, por eso puedes llamar al método `venderHierva` sobre ese resultado. Pero `venderHierva` no devuelve nada, por tanto no puedes llamar al método `.sobornar`.

Comment: No estás aplicando para nada programación funcional. En Java, sino me equivoco, para emplear dicho paradigma puedes hacer uso de streams y lambdas.

Comment: Más que *programación funcional* parece más que estás tratando de implementar el patrón de diseño *Builder*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera invocación funciona porque el método devuelve una instancia de la clase, la siguiente invocación falla porque el método no devuelve nada (`void`), es decir estás tratando de llamar un método fuera de una clase y no tiene sentido.  Si quieres encadenar las llamadas de los métodos tendrías que modificar tus métodos así:

```
public Camello metodo(/* parámetros */) {
    // ...
    return this;
}
```

Así devuelves la misma clase sobre la que estás trabajando en cada invocación y puedes continuar agregándo llamadas.

Comment: Okey, grácias, ya me funciona, pero...por que necesita que le devuelva algo? No lo entiendo

Comment: Cada llamada se hace sobre el último objeto que has devuelto, si no devuelves algo ¿sobre qué objeto se está invocando el método?.  Poner puntos seguidos no significa que todo se llame sobre el primer objeto.